# Vidyo.io media bridge recorder does not work

Tags: vidyo

I am developing an application using the vidyo platform (https://vidyo.io). In particular, I am trying to record the videoconference using the Media Bridge Docker.

I have followed these two tutorials:

[media-bridge-integration](https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/115006198708-Integrate-the-Media-Bridge-Docker-Image-with-your-Vidyo-io-based-Application#destination)

[hot-to-record-with-media-bridge](https://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/record-video-chat/)

In both scenarios, I am able to create and start the recorder, but at the end, I do not find the "recording.flv" file (that should have been generated by the recorder).

I have checked from the point of view of the participants, and they see the recorder. In fact, the message "Recorder joined" is showed in all the participants' views.

I have installed the Media Bridge Docker on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS.

Has someone the same problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

The recorder was working correctly, but the file recording.flv was saved inside the my_vidyombws container instead of my_mediabridge.